# How to merge two dataframes specifying specific columns? (R)

Tags: r

I have two dataframes that I want to join together. `df1` is the original dataframe and I created `df2` earlier in my workflow where I conducted additional analysis.

I want to join only `var3` using `ID` as the common ID, which means `var4` will be excluded from the join. For the merged `df3`, when an ID is not present in `df1` from `df2`, the value for `var3` should be 0.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- tibble(ID = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004), var1 = c(1,0,1,0), var2 = c(0,1,1,0))
df2 <- tibble(ID = c(1001, 1002), var3 = c(1,1), var4 = c(0, 0))
```

**Table 1 (df1):**

| ID | var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | 0 |
| 1002 | 0 | 1 |
| 1003 | 1 | 1 |
| 1004 | 0 | 0 |

**Table 2 (df2):**

| ID | var3 | var4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | 0 |
| 1002 | 1 | 0 |

**Joined Table (df3):**

| ID | var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1002 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1003 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1004 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr::left_join` to merge `df1` with a version of `df2` that contains only "ID" and "var3". Then `mutate` the "var" columns to replace NA (missing) values with 0.

```
df3 <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(select(df2, ID, var3), by = 'ID') %>% 
  mutate(across(-ID, ~replace_na(., 0)))   

     ID  var1  var2  var3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  1001     1     0     1
2  1002     0     1     1
3  1003     1     1     0
4  1004     0     0     0
```

There are several valid ways to select the "var" columns within `across`. Here I've used `-ID`. One could also use `starts_with('var')` or even `everything()`, though the latter assumes no NA values in "ID".